# How to apply filmic tone mapping per pixel

Tags: vb.net, graphics

I am not going to attempt to fully understand all this stuff, but I would like to know how to apply the formulae of filmic tone mapping to the pixels of an image I input, outputting the tone-mapped image at the end, programmatically.

Right now I've got, for the RGB of each pixel:

```
Function f(x) 
  return x*(A*x+C*B)+D*E)/(x*(A*x+B)+D*F)) - E/F
End Function

'code for reading bitmap I want to affect, pixel by pixel, and looping the below:

For each pixel
 Dim new_r = f(orig_r)/f(W)
 Dim new_g = f(orig_g)/f(W)
 Dim new_b = f(orig_b)/f(W)
'code to write pixel to newly forming bitmap
Next

'code to save and display bitmap
```

However, this doesn't work as the result of f(r/g/b)/f(W) is a number very close to 1, rather than a sensible RGB 0-255 value, so clearly I am not getting this.

Also I haven't ^0.45'd or anything like that - not sure if I should, or at which point.

I code in VB.NET and all the examples of this are in C, which I just don't understand, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear enough, "code to write pixel to newly forming bitmap" uses the new_r, new_g and new_b values for said pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tone-mapping formulas are set up to work for linear color values between 0 and 1. So, just convert your RGB values to double and divide by 255 to get to this range, do tone-mapping, and multiply the result by 255 to get to the original range again.

```
Dim origRNormalized = CDbl(orig_r) / 255.0
'...
Dim new_r = Math.Round(f(origRNormalized)/f(W) * 255.0)
'...
'Make sure that the values are still in the 0-255 range
```

Be aware that this might introduce color artefacts to an 8-bit image since the color resolution is already pretty low.

The `^0.45` or `^(1 / 2.2)` is the so called gamma correction. It is meant to counter the color mapping that screens do on their own. You need to do this if you save to a gamma-corrected file format (which most of them are). Do this with the `Double` values in the `0-1` range, not the quantized values. And if your input is already a gamma-corrected image, you need to do the forward transform (`^2.2`) at the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed! You really rock! After reading literally every page on the internet that contains the minimum keywords to potentially describe the solution and not finding anything (unless buried in page after page of irrelevant info), you've answered it so perfectly and so exactly and so concisely, really appreciate it

Comment: Any tips on speeding up the code? It's got a division so is especially slow (I've got the f(W) outside the loop and inverted, can't think of much else!)

Comment: @Dr.Kaii : Regarding speed I sincerely doubt that division is the bottleneck. These days standard math is not a problem for the modern processor. Rather, I think it's the reading/setting of the pixels in the bitmap that's causing it to go slow (which you haven't shown us _how_ you do). If you're using a .NET `Bitmap` you should look into how you can modify its pixel data using the `Bitmap.LockBits()` method. If you want further help with optimization you can ask over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, will do. I am indeed using lockbits, but it's still really slow. I'll check out your forum. Ideally I want to get this working on the GPU but I've really gone through all of the various suggestions and never been able to figure them out! Maybe I am in deeper water than I can swim in yet :)

Comment: @Dr.Kaii : To manipulate an image on the GPU you would need to use a graphics API like DirectX or OpenGL. I've worked a little bit with the former, and while it certainly is possible it isn't as easy as using GDI/GDI+. Using a pixel shader is probably the fastest and most powerful way, but passing the image back and forth from the CPU and GPU requires at least decent knowledge of the API.

Comment: If the values were display referred, aka 0.0 to 1.0, you wouldn't need a unique transfer function / tone mapping in the first place. Scene referred values extend from 0.0 to infinity, and as such, "gamma" and other basic power function approaches won't work.